# Tree using angular sometimes goes 5 levels deep, sometimes it goes less, Need jquery to hide when it goes less

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tree using angular sometimes goes 5 levels deep, sometimes it goes less, I need a jQuery selector to hide the button when it goes less than 5 levels deep.

Please refer to the code snippet.

The groupToggle function shows or hides the child and changes the + to a negative or vice versa.

The .clsGrpToggle function is where I'm having problems.  I'm not sure how to get the controller to work in the snippet.

```js
function groupToggle(symbolObj) {
        var symbolTxt = $(symbolObj).text();
        if (symbolTxt == "+") {
            $(symbolObj).text("-");
//            $(".groupList").show();  //shows all
            $(symbolObj).siblings(".groupList").show();
        }
        if (symbolTxt == "-") {
            $(symbolObj).text("+");
//            $(".groupList").hide();  //hides all
            $(symbolObj).siblings(".groupList").hide();
        }
    }

$(".clsGrpToggle").each(function() {
            if($(this).closest("li").has("ul")){
                console.log("if " + $(this).siblings().html());
//                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                console.log("else " + $(this).siblings().html());
//                $(this).hide();

            }
        });

.controller('MockRbacGroupController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

        $scope.roles = [
            {

                name: "role1"
            },

            {
                name: "role2"
            }];
        $scope.users = [
            {
                role: "role1",
                subUsers: [{
                    name: "agent1"
                },
                    {
                        name: "agent2"
                    }]

            }
        ];

    })
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 232px; left: 870px;" ng-controller="mockRbacGroupController">
        <tr>
            <th>Roles</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in groupList | orderBy:'group'">
            <td>
                <button onclick="groupToggle(this);" class="clsGrpToggle">&#43;</button>&nbsp;{{group.name}}
                <ul class="groupList" style="display: none;" ng-repeat="group in group.children">
                    <li><button onclick="groupToggle(this);" class="clsGrpToggle">&#43;</button>&nbsp;{{group.name}}
                        <ul class="groupList" style="display: none;" ng-repeat="group in group.children">
                            <li><button onclick="groupToggle(this);" class="clsGrpToggle">&#43;</button>&nbsp;{{group.name}}
                                <ul class="groupList" style="display: none;" ng-repeat="group in group.children">
                                    <li><button onclick="groupToggle(this);" class="clsGrpToggle">&#43;</button>&nbsp;{{group.name}}
                                        <ul class="groupList" style="display: none;" ng-repeat="group in group.children">
                                            <li>{{group.name}}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thought process is wrong for angular.  Can use a directive to create the nesting elements and/or use `nf-if`. Either way you would not be creating elements for levels that don't exist. No need to make it more complicated adding jQuery in

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: for starters try `ng-if="group.children.length"`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was ng-if="group.children.length" on the button.  Thanks to charlieftl who provided the answer.